# Using type hints to ensure that two function parameters are of the same type

Tags: python, type-hinting

Say I have a function that retrieves a value from a source, then maps it to another type before returning it.

An example function declaration might look like this:

```py
def get_value(mapping_function: Callable[[str], any]) -> any:
    # ...
```

The function would retrieve the value from some source and then map it according to the `mapping_function` before returning the result.

Is there any way I can specify that the returned type and the result of the lambda would be of the same type? It could be *any* type, but it will always be the same, something like the following:

```py
def get_value(mapping_function: Callable[[str], T]) -> T:
    # ...
```

For example, in Java, I could do:

```java
public static <T> T getValue(Function<String, T> mappingFunction) {
  // ...
}
```

Maybe I wrap it in a class with a generic type or something?

Comment: It looks like you already have your answer.

Comment: This is discussed in the typing module's documentation on [Generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def get_value(mapping_function: Callable[[str], T]) -> T:
    # ...
```

Comment: positional arguments will constrain the type from Any to some list:  `T = TypeVar('T', int, float, complex)`